# How to elevate collapsing toolbar above main layout like the floating button?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-elevation

How can I set my collapsing toolbar above the activity layout ?

I want to "elevate" it like the floating button. I have tried to set an elevation on the appbarlayout, even on the collapsing toolbar but it doesn't work.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in `CoordinatorLayout`. you can find a lot of examples online here's a nice one:

[Creating collapsing effects](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#creating-collapsing-effects)

Comment: I have edited my question, it should be clearer now. I am currently using the `CollapsingToolbarLayout `and the CoordinatorLayout but I can't get the floating button effect on it